# .NET Core application on Linux slow to crash the first time

Tags: linux, exception, .net-core

I'm running a .NET Core 2.0 console EXE on Ubuntu 16.04. The application terminates with an unhandled exception - which can be anything, e.g. this is enough:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Test .NET core exception.");
    }
```

The first time this happens on a given machine there is noticeable delay (2 seconds or so) between the time it prints

`Unhandled Exception: System.ApplicationException: Test .NET core exception.`

and the time it prints
`Aborted (core dumped)`
and the process dies. During this time the process uses all of one CPU. (No core files is actually created.)

If I run the application again there is no such delay any more. What is it doing during that first crash and how do I prevent this delay to let it crash quickly? The delay is only a second for a trivial application that just throws an exception, but can be 20-30 seconds for one that uses a lot of RAM.

Running with `/usr/bin/time -v dotnet CoreConsoleApp1.dll` the first time:

`Unhandled Exception: System.ApplicationException: Test .NET core exception.
   at CoreConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in CoreConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 20
Command terminated by signal 6
        Command being timed: "dotnet CoreConsoleApp1.dll"
        User time (seconds): 0.04
        System time (seconds): 0.02
        Percent of CPU this job got: 1%
        Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:05.92
        Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
        Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
        Average stack size (kbytes): 0
        Average total size (kbytes): 0
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 32388
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
        Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 193
        Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 2708
        Voluntary context switches: 1358
        Involuntary context switches: 29
        Swaps: 0
        File system inputs: 57736
        File system outputs: 0
        Socket messages sent: 0
        Socket messages received: 0
        Signals delivered: 0
        Page size (bytes): 4096
        Exit status: 0`

The second time:

`Unhandled Exception: System.ApplicationException: Test .NET core exception.
   at CoreConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in CoreConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 20
Command terminated by signal 6
        Command being timed: "dotnet CoreConsoleApp1.dll"
        User time (seconds): 0.03
        System time (seconds): 0.00
        Percent of CPU this job got: 26%
        Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.16
        Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
        Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
        Average stack size (kbytes): 0
        Average total size (kbytes): 0
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 29416
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
        Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
        Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 2413
        Voluntary context switches: 26
        Involuntary context switches: 33
        Swaps: 0
        File system inputs: 0
        File system outputs: 0
        Socket messages sent: 0
        Socket messages received: 0
        Signals delivered: 0
        Page size (bytes): 4096
        Exit status: 0`

The project was built in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.

`$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
$ uname -a
Linux evgeny-linux 4.4.0-1052-aws #61-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 23:05:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P`

Comment: Can you provide more details? What exact code are you seeing this problem with? How are you building and running (exact commands, please)? What exactly is your OS (and how are you with updates)? What does `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` say? Can you show us the output of `/usr/bin/time -v <your actual command to run your dotnet program here>` for the first time and subsequent runs?

Comment: @omajid I've edited in the requested info, thanks.

Comment: I tried changing `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to a simple filename ("thecore") and that seems to eliminate the delay - although a core file is still not created for some reason.